# Insert/Update Entity in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am writing a crawler that should go to a website, extract some data from there and then store it into a db, the thing is the crawler should also update the data that has already been found in a prior run.

The `ParseDataPage` returns the information parsed from the site in a EF POCO, one of its properties is a unique identifier (which also is the primary key in the db table), how can I tell EF to insert/add the object?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        var context = (adCreatorEntities) DbContextFactory.GetInstance().GetDbContext<adCreatorEntities>();
        var crawler = new DataCrawler();            
        crawler.Login();
        var propertyIds = crawler.GetPropertyIds();

        foreach (var id in propertyIds)
        {
            var poco = crawler.ParseDataPage(id);
            context.Properties.Add(poco); //<-- How can I tell EF to update if the record exists or to insert it otherwise??
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

        if (crawler.LoggedIn)
            crawler.Logout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the entity state to `Modified` or Add the entity to the `DbSet` based on the key's value.

```
if(entity.propertyId <= 0)
{
    context.Properties.Add(poco); 
}
else
{
      context.Entry(poco).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

This is code for EF5, EF4 is slightly different for setting object state

```
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(poco, EntityState.Modified);
```

Comment: I still don't get it. I mean, after I call `var poco = parseDataPage(id)`, poco.Id will always be set. Be it a new record or an existing one. So should I always do `var poco = parseDataPage(id); poco.State=EntityState.Modified; context.Properties.Attach(poco);`??

Comment: My code assumes that a new poco won't have an id `<=0`. I would recommend `parseDataPage` not set ID in the case where it's a new object, otherwise you have to make an additional call to check for existence, among other problems.

Answer (score 1):

you can check whether record exists or not using following code,

```
 var entity= dataContext.Properties.Find(b => b.UniqueId == poco.UniqueId);
                    if (entity== null)
                    {
                        dataContext.Properties.Add(poco);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                   dataContext.SaveChanges();
```